# Kotlin Extensions - Inflate Custom Views

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm new to kotlin, I Have an adapter class and I need to inflate a view. but recently I'm facing an error saying `"Unresolved reference: R"`

Like in the image below :

[image]

So, how can I inflate this view? I have imported the following:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.slide_layout.view.*
```

But I can't figure out what should i do next, I searched everywhere, but they all seem outdated! so what should i do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not all answers here can solve your  problem, I've  been looking  for general solutions, you can find them 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510869/9005383)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues i can think of,

1. The first is a missing import to the R class, if your adapter is in an inner package from your domain package name, i.e.

   - assume this is the domain package 'your.doamin.package'
   - if adapter is not in that package i.e. adapter is in 'your.domain.package.adapter'
     then you need to import the R class into that file, i.e write this import statement

`import your.domain.package.R`

That should fix your problem for this scenario

2. If you have already done '1' above then the other issue is, Sometimes Android studio just misbehaves, so close the file and clean and build your project by first clicking, Build -> Clean Project, once the build is done reopen that file.

Comment: still having the same problem even after many rebuilds, screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ke6brs

Comment: @TamimProduction try this, since you have the import, run the application in an emulator or device, and tell me if it crashes because of the R class, lets eliminate some possibilitiies

Comment: @TamimProduction try this, since you have the import, first do this clean the build by going to menu: Build -> Clean Project, then build and run the application in an emulator or device, and tell me if it crashes because of the R class, lets eliminate some possibilitiies,

Comment: it doesn't even build :/

Comment: Yh its not supposed to build sorry, then try this, it is possibly something else that is causing the R class madness, and it is possible that you have a bug somewhere else that is preventing the app from building, to figure that out, comment out this part of your code that uses the R class, and try and build your project, and make sure that it builds: fix any other missing imports and make sure it builds without the R class, once it builds successfully, uncomment that R class part, and rebuild.

Comment: more errors happening , i think i'm gonna start a new project and see if it's still occuring

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177332/discussion-between-ebi-igweze-and-tamim-production).

Answer (score 0):

For resolving the error `unresolved reference: R`, you are missing import of your `R` file. Something like

```
import packageName.R
```

For your reference, I am attaching a screenshot of the error and see the commented import. [image]
So check where your `R.java` resides and import that.

Comment: still having the same problem even after many rebuilds, screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ke6brs

Comment: Do you have the right package defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

First you check your class import statement in that your R class file imported or not.

```
import packageName.R
```

also you can set android studio provide auto import features. if you can enable this feature then all required class automatically import your .kt class