# error; Unresolved reference for activity_main and app_name in Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am learning to work with the camerax library in Android on Google codelab.

They have an incomplete code for the project with which we have to work.

I did everything as instructed, and I think nothing is wrong from my side but still, the code is giving error: unresolved reference for activity_main and app_name.

What could be the possible reasons? I have tried 're-building' the project and restarting the Android studio. Image is added.[image]

Comment: Check the import for R . You must have imported wrong R .

Comment: I have used this to import R: import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

Comment: Thats not R import . Its should be `import your_application_package_name.R`.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. Can you tell me more about R, resources? There are many so why there are many R?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue caused when you import the wrong **R**. Check your imports as @ADM already commented.

Comment: I have used this to import R: import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621301/android-studio-3-1-3-unresolved-reference-r-kotlin check out this thread. Might get some answers.